# Ubuntu GUI only works in Safe Mode (Hybrid Graphic Driver : AMD 8650G with HD 8970M)

Tags: drivers, 20.04, gui

So this is my first experience with Linux and excuse me if I say something wrong. I am trying to get a Home Server running with an Old Laptop. SSH is working fine, but I cant get the GUI working.

Some Details:

- OS : Ubuntu 20.04 LS
- Graphic Card : Hybrid (AMD Radeon HD 8970M / AMD HD 8650G)
- Laptop : MSI GX60 3 BE

The most likely cause is the old Hybrid Graphic Card. When I "startx" through Recovery Mode, GUI is working correctly. But if I do that during Normal Boot, the system restarts.

There is an additional error when running startx (not present in Recovery Mode)
"No VRAM object for PCIE GART." and "startup failed on resume" (not sure how to log this since system restarts within a couple of seconds)

I don't plan to use the Graphic Card so doesn't matter if the drivers are outdated, just need the server to load into GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Well I loaded my laptop with an unlocked bios, playing around with every setting. What I did found was when you enabled `_ohc` to `pci0` the laptop would take forever to boot, unless you took the battery out pressed on the power button for 30secs. Additionally it would disable all i/o including wifi.

Not sure why, but after I logged out, and got it booting quick again this is what I found.

```
   product: Richland [Radeon HD 8650G]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:feb00000-

feb3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Neptune XT [Radeon HD 8970M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff 
memory:fea00000-fea3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea40000-fea5ffff
```

Under capabilities and configuration, it used to be disabled